# How can I install different versions of PHP in xampp

Tags: php, lamp, xampp

I installed the latest version of xampp i.e. 1.8.3-2 in ubuntu 12.04.

I found that it include php 5.5.6 and I want the lesser php version to work on my site.
How can i install the new version or multiple version in xampp so that my site can work.
I am working on magento and it does not support php 5.5 so any idea how can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: You can see http://meows.us/my-life/running-multiple-versions-of-xampp-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: https://github.com/rafaelphp/lampp_switcher

Answer (score -1):

I dont't know if it is possible but you can install it manualy from the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5
```

and then type your password for the user. And open firefox and type

```
http://localhost/
```

You dont need XAMP to run the apache or php server now